# Is it possible to view info on each VBA command directly in Excel?

Tags: vba, excel

VBA stands for "Visual Basic for Applications". So far, I figured out that right clicking on the Module window gives the option to see all Visual Basic commands as a list. However, no information on each individual command was provided. I checked on the internet for the most up-to-date list of command information, but the answers were:
1) Irrelevant
2) Not up-to-date
Does anyone know a way to view built-in VBA command information on excel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Open Excel File

2) Press ALT + F11

3) Select View ===> Object Browser.

It will show all the classes associated with Excel

Select VBA for VBA related commands/functions.

[image]

Comment: You should mention that selecting **VBA** from the `<All Libraries>` will show all the **VBA** commands available.

Comment: @ThomasInzina Thanks for the udate.

Comment: No problem.  Good answer.  It earned my +1.